# How to delete the displayed time before an event title

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Every event displayed on fullcalendar has a title, but it is with start time. How to delete it to just display as what i set. Do i have to modify the source code or how to set it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css as well as jQuery to hide it.

Css:

```
 .fc-time: {display:none;}
```

jQuery:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    $('.fc-time', element).hide();
}
```

Comment: you have sovled  my probem .

Comment: If you find this answer helpful then please accept this answer so that other developer can get help from your question and my answer.

Comment: Why rendering the fields to hide them, if it's possible to do not render them from the beginning? Just follow the documentation http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/timeFormat/

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove the time in your events displays, just add to the fullcalendar initialization the following line:

```
 timeFormat:  ' ',
```

If you want a custom time format, just visit [the timeFormat doc](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/timeFormat/)